# Angular 6 custom directive not updating after value change

Tags: angular

I want to  make a dynamic menu, the menu itself has css class in which if i check a checkbox the menu has to change position from left to right.

Right now the directive works, but only once, when the program loads, if i try to change the check the checkbox within the program nothing happens.

the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="app-menu" adjustSide side="{{position}}">

            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>

</div>
```

I tried with `(side)="position"`, `[side]="position"` and `[(side)]="position"`.

And the directive:

```
  @Input('side') private side:string;


    private el: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor( private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef ) { 
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement; 
    }

     ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {

        if (this.side == 'left') {
            this.renderer.addClass(this.el, 'offset-left');
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el, 'offset-right');
        }else{
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el, 'offset-left');
            this.renderer.addClass(this.el, 'offset-right');
        }
    }
```

I'm still learning angular, so for some reason i don't understand why it seems the new value doesn't reach to the directive, but i have no idea why.

What i'm doing wrong? did i missed something?

Comment: hi, the right way to handle @Input is the `[side]=position`. BTW you could also use the `@HostBinding`. can you prepare a minimal example on stackblitz ??

Comment: Can you give any fiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Behavior Subject.

**Component:**

```
public sub = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
this.sub.next('left');
```

**Directive:**

```
@Input('side') side: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(){
    if(this.side){
      this.side.subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
      });

    }
  }
  ngOnChanges(){

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

Just use the `adjustSide` as an `@Input` alias so that you don't have to declare other properties on your directive.

Just use it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="app-menu" [adjustSide]="position">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the directive should be like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[adjustSide]'
})
export class AdjustSizeDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input('adjustSide') side: string;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges() {

    console.log('Side changed to : ', this.side);

    if (this.side == 'left') {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'offset-left');
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'offset-right');
    }
    else{
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'offset-left');
        this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'offset-right');
    }
  }

}
```

If you have a look at the console, you'll see the `ngOnChanges` getting called. I've logged the value of `this.side` through that.

Here's a [StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyyxgi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your case.

Comment: While it works in your sample, in my angular program it doesn't. Any ideas on how i can debug this?

Comment: I provided you with the sample so that it could help you debug by comparing what you've done differently. Can you create a StackBlitz replicating your issue?