# Update visibility of HTML element through directive

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have a directive that shows or hides an HTML element [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hg5zno) :

```
<div *authorize="'A'">
  Visible when letter is A
</div>
```

And the Authorize directive is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[authorize]'
})

export class AuthorizeDirective implements OnInit {

  letter: string;

  @Input() set authorize(letter: string) {
    this.letter = letter;
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private authorizationService: AuthorizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() { 

    this.authorizationService.authorize(this.letter).subscribe(x => {
      x ? this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef) : this.viewContainer.clear();
    });    

  }

}
```

The authorization service and its authorize method is:

```
export class AuthorizationService {

  private notifier: Subscription;

  private data$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private noteService: NoteService) {

     this.data$ = of(['A', 'B']);
     this.data$.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); 

     this.notifier = this.noteService.get().subscribe((code: number) => { 

       if (code == 0) {
         this.data$ = of(['C', 'D']);
         this.data$.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); 
       }

    });

  }        

  authorize(letter: string) : Observable<boolean> {

    return this.data$.pipe(
      map(data => data.indexOf(letter) > -1)
    );

  }

}
```

On a real scenario `data$` is obtained from API using HTTPClient.

And the NoteService is:

```
export class NoteService {

  private subject = new Subject<number>();

  send(code: number) {
    this.subject.next(code);
  }

  clear() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  get(): Observable<number> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

When a `note` with code 0 is emitted `data$` is also updated ...

That should update the visibility of the elements that uses the directive.

On StackBlitz example by clicking the button the Div with C should appear.

But it is not doing that ... How to trigger that?

Comment: its really not clear to me! Do you want to access directive from service? Or what? Can you provide sample working demo?

Comment: No ... In the service I am updating the `data$` inside `if (note.code == 0) { }`. When that happens I want the directive to update the visibility of the element. Like calling authorize again ... Because with the new data$ the result of authorize might be different.

Comment: Will this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953651/angular-6-custom-directive-not-updating-after-value-change)? I mean try `ngOnChanges()`

Comment: In which way? Using a `BehaviorSubject`? Not sure how to integrate that in. the directive or if something would change on the `AuthorizationService`.

Comment: Provide me a stackblitz will try!

Comment: Could you provide more code from your template/component. Where is `userId` and `user` coming from?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I updated my question with a StackBlitz example and also updated the code in the question according to it. In the example the Div with C should appear when clicking the button as it changes `data$`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hg5zno

Comment: @fridoo I updated my question with a StackBlitz example and also updated the code in the question according to it. In the example the Div with C should appear when clicking the button as it changes `data$`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hg5zno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed up a few things for you. The biggest issue was how you were setting up your mock auth service... it wasn't really getting the job done due to how observables work, if you use `of`, that's a static observable, so you have no way of calling next on it and updating subscribers. you needed a static subject to leverage, like so:

```
private dataSource = new ReplaySubject<string[]>(1);
private data$: Observable<string[]> = this.dataSource.asObservable();

constructor(private noteService: NoteService) {

  this.dataSource.next(['A','B']);
  this.data$.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // this will fire everytime next is called now

  this.notifier = this.noteService.get().subscribe((code: number) => { 
    if (code == 0) {
      this.dataSource.next(['C', 'D']);
    }
  });
}
```

this way you can call next and subscribers get the update.  This fix alone will fix the problem.

But I also touched up your directive to allow the letter to change dynamically and be more efficient:

```
private hasView = false; // this variable will prevent unneeded template clearing / creating
private letterSource = new Subject<string>()
private sub: Subscription
@Input() set authorize(letter: string) {
  this.letterSource.next(letter); // call next here on this subject to reauth if the letter input changes
}

constructor(private element: ElementRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private authorizationService: AuthorizationService) {
  this.sub = this.letterSource.pipe(
    switchMap(letter => this.authorizationService.authorize(letter))
  ).subscribe(x => {
    if (x && !this.hasView) { // only recreate the view if it's not already there
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
      this.hasView = true;
    } else if (!x && this.hasView) { // only clear it if it is
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      this.hasView = false;
    }
  })
}
```

1. directives usually have an expectation that you can change their input and they will update accordingly, even if you don't anticipate it in this case, it's best to account for it.
2. preventing the view from clearing / recreating when not needed can actually have huge performance implications if this directive in used on an element that contains many sub components, which it very well may someday. Best to be as efficient as possible with a structural directive.

fixed blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wlvlkr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauthorize.directive.ts

Comment: It is not working correctly. If you click the button twice C will disappear on the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Change data$ to behavior subject, when data$ is `of()` it is not an hot observable and will only emit once when subscribed. Btw you should simplify the structure a bit. it is really no need for so many files

```
 this.data$ = new BehaviorSubject(['A', 'B']);
 this.data$.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); 

 this.notifier = this.noteService.get().subscribe((code: number) => { 

   if (code == 0) {
     this.data$.next(['C', 'D']);
     this.data$.subscribe(x => console.warn(x)); 
   }
```

Comment: Could you fork by example? I tried your code but it does not seem to work.