# Value passed to directive is sometimes undefined

Tags: angular, angular8

On an Angular component I have the following:

```js
export class PostAboutComponent implements OnInit {

  postId: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(parameters => {
      this.postId = parameters.has('postId') ? +parameters.get('postId') : undefined;
    })
  }
}
```

On the component's HTML I have:

```html
<p *authorize="'EditPost'; id postId">
  <button (click)="editPost()">Edit post</button>
</p>
```

The authorize directive is the following:

```js
export class AuthorizeDirective implements OnInit {

  private notifier: Subscription;

  requirement: Requirement;
  id: number;

  @Input() set authorize(requirement: string) {
    this.requirement = Requirement[requirement];
  }

  @Input() set authorizeId(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private template: TemplateRef<any>, private container: ViewContainerRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private authorizationService: AuthorizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() { 

    console.log("id: " + this.id);

    this.authorizationService.authorize(this.requirement, this.id).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged()
    ).subscribe(x => {
      x ? this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template) : this.container.clear();
    });
  }
}
```

What happens is that sometimes `id` is `undefined` in the Authorize directive in:

```
console.log("id: " + this.id);
```

Other times it is not ... And if I refresh the page is never undefined.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You retrieve the id asynchronously in your component so when your directive is created and its `ngOnInit` runs it might not have been retrieved yet. You could work with a Subject like `this.letterSource` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217375/9423231 or move your logic into a setter like here https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-appunless-property (add a `console.log` to `@Input() set authorizeId` to see that the id gets set twice) or move the logic to [ngOnChanges()](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change HTML as follows for binding to work,

In order to bind value to structural directive identifier, use `identifier_name: valueToBind`

```html
<p *authorize="'EditPost'; id: postId">
  <button (click)="editPost()">Edit post</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you sure `this.postId` has value in controller?

Comment: Yes, it has value in the component ... I am trying to figure if the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You can check if `@Input` is getting called or not by adding console log in `@Input` set methods.